# How To Dropdown with search Php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I want my dropdown list with search php with mysql. This is my code:

```
<td> Urgency (SLA)*</td>
<td> : </td>
<td>
    <select name="sla">
    <?php 
        $sla = $slas->get_sla();
        echo '<option value="'.$slaval['slaid'].'" selected="selected">'.$slaval['namasla'].'</option>';
        foreach ($sla as $slaval) 
        {   
            echo '<option value="'.$slaval['slaid'].'">'.$slaval['namasla'].'</option>';
        }
    ?>
    </select>
```

Comment: And what's happening when you execute the code?p.s. slasval outside the loop is undefined...

Comment: just dropdown , no with search .

Comment: remove first `echo` with `option` before `foreach`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the first echo with option before foreach, $slasval outside the loop is undefined.

```
<td> Urgency (SLA)*</td><td> : </td>
<td>
  <select name="sla">
    <?php 
        $sla = $slas->get_sla();
        foreach ($sla as $slaval) 
        {
            echo '<option value="'.$slaval['slaid'].'">'.$slaval['namasla'].'</option>';
        }
    ?>
    </select>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<td> Urgency (SLA)*</td><td> : </td>
        <td><select name="sla">
            <?php 
                $sla = $slas->get_sla();
                foreach ($sla as $slaval) 
                {   echo '<option value="'.$slaval['slaid'].'">'.$slaval['namasla'].'</option>';
                }
            ?>
            </select>
```

In first echo you see that there is no variable by name of

```
$slaval
```

variable, the variable is available inside foreach loop.

Answer (score -1):

Try using a Datalist It might help you in selecting the dropdown

```
<td> Urgency (SLA)*</td><td> : </td>
<td><select name="sla" list="selectlist">
<datalist id='selectlist'>
<?php 
     $sla = $slas->get_sla();
     echo '<option value="'.$slaval['slaid'].'" selected="selected">'.$slaval['namasla'].'</option>';
     foreach ($sla as $slaval) 
     {
     echo '<option value="'.$slaval['slaid'].'">'.$slaval['namasla'].'</option>';
     }
?>
```